# Knockout Validation custom rules are not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am unable to get custom rules to work. I'm afraid I'm failing to understand something fundamental. In this example, `b`, `bvm` and `berr` all validated as expected off of the `required` extender. Against my custom extender `foo`, `a`,`avm` and `aerr` do not fail validation as expected.

Calling `console.log()` from within `validator` demonstrates that the validator is not being fired. The only way I was able to get the validator function to fire is by calling `ko.registerExtenders` after the init (although there is no reason to do this, `registerExtenders` is enabled by default. If it is called, `validator` is triggered when I reference the extender creating the observable array.

[Here's my fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/musicalshore/c7xynchp/6/)

```
ko.validation.init({
    grouping: {
        deep: true,
        live: true,
        observable: true
    }
});

ko.validation.rules['foo'] = {
    validator: function(arr) {
        if (!arr.length) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    message: 'Please foo.'
};
var a = ko.observableArray().extend({ foo: true });
var avm = ko.validatedObservable({
    a: a
});
var aerr = ko.validation.group([a]);

var b = ko.observableArray().extend({ required: true });
var bvm = ko.validatedObservable({
    b: b
});
var berr = ko.validation.group([b]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of the init isn't as critical as having a call to registerExtenders after your custom extender. If you omit that line the custom extenders will just be ignored, as you've experienced.

https://jsfiddle.net/c7xynchp/12/

```
var log = console.debug.bind(console, '[Debug]');
ko.validation.rules['foo'] = {
    validator: function(arr) {
        log('validator', arguments);
        if (!arr.length) {
            log('invalid');
            return false;
        } else {
            log('valid', arr);
            return true;
        }
    },
    message: 'Please select at least one vendor.'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
var a = ko.observableArray().extend({ foo: true });
var avm = ko.validatedObservable({
    a: a
});
var aerr = ko.validation.group([a]);

var b = ko.observableArray().extend({ required: true });
var bvm = ko.validatedObservable({
    b: b
});
var berr = ko.validation.group([b]);
ko.validation.init({
    grouping: {
        deep: true,
        live: true,
        observable: true
    }
});

log('a', a.isValid());
log('avm', avm.isValid());
log('aerr', aerr());
log('b', b.isValid());
log('bvm', bvm.isValid());
log('berr', berr());

// just for laughs
log('aberr', ko.validation.group([a,b])());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize the validation plugin after you have registered all your custom validation rules (call the `ko.validation.init` fn after you register your `foo` validation rule).

My guess is that when you initialize the plugin, it will work with the configuration and rules registered before, so all the custom rules registered after will not be taken into account (unless, as you pointed out, you call `registerExtenders`, which will force to register again all custom extenders).

Also see that, for custom rules registered specifically for one object (see my modification on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/elbecita/c7xynchp/10/), they are always taken into account no matter when you initialize the validation plugin.

Hope it helps!